# Integration tests not getting executed

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing

I have some junit tests and htmlunit integration tests in one of my maven project. The problem is that my integration tests are not getting executed when I run

```
mvn clean test
```

## Junit Tests Here:

webstore\src\test\java\com\istore\dao\AddressTest.java

## Integration Tests Here:

webstore\src\test\java\com\istore\presentation\htmlunit\PageTests.java

How does mvn determines that AddressTest.java should execute and other one should not?

Comment: What testing framework run unit/integration tests? I guess Junit for unittests so your test methods are annotated with `@Test` or the test classes extend `TestCase` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved after executing following command:

```
mvn failsafe:integration-test
```

Answer (score 3):

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes describes the expected filepatterns.

btw, if you are talking about integration tests, have a look at the maven-failsafe-plugin. It uses *IT.java as file pattern

Answer (score 2):

### The problem is suffix `Tests`, should be `Test` in your `PageTests.java`!

---

> By default, the [Surefire Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) will automatically include all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> - `**/Test*.java` - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that start with `Test`.
> - `**/*Test.java` - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that end with `Test`.
> - `**/*TestCase.java` - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that end with `TestCase`.

[Maven Failsafe Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) is for integration tests and uses suffix `IT`. To invoke integration tests with Failsafe Plugin use

```
mvn verify
```

References:

- [Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) in Surefire
- [Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) in Failsafe

Comment: As soon as I renamed PageTests.java to PageTest.java it worked ! Thanks for the pointer. I am reading some documents and online tutorial which states that integration tests should not be executed along with unit tests. Thanks for the quick pointer though.